# How could I reject the inclusion of a variable in a regression model?

Tags: statistics

Not sure how to phrase this properly, but is there a test that can help me say statistically that a variable should not be included in a model? Essentially, how could I test this hypothesis:

Ho: x helps predict y

Ha: x does not help predict y

Answer (score 0):

In simple linear regression model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\varepsilon$, $X$ does not help predict $Y$ means that $\beta_1=0$. This should be the main hypothesis $H_0$. With alternative $H_a$: $\beta_1\neq 0$.

To test $H_0$, assume $\varepsilon_i$ are independent random variables with $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution. And use test statistic
$$
T = \dfrac{\hat{\beta}_1}{se(\hat{\beta}_1)}
$$
which distribution under $H_0$ is Student T distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom where $n$ is total number of observations.

Here $\hat{\beta}_1$ is the least square estimate of $\beta_1$ and 
$$
\left(se(\hat{\beta}_1)\right)^2 = \frac{\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)^2}
$$

The null-hypothesis $H_0$ is accepted at $\alpha$-level when $|T|<t_{n-2,\,\alpha}$. Here $t_{n-2,\,\alpha}$ is critical value for Student $T_{n-2}$ distribution corresponding two tails with total area $\alpha$.